# Would it cause problems if I wear the same clothes for the second job interview as I did for the first one?

Tags: interviewing, dress-code

Can I have the same clothes on me on two job interviews in one company?

Comment: Depends.  If you were wearing a suit and tie, I would at least wear a different tie, because it's the kind of thing your interviewers may have been looking at throughout.  Also, a tie is the kind of thing you might like but your interview thinks is ugly.  So they will remember that.

Comment: As Joe said unless you wore a lime green suit with a top hat and a cape they won't even notice.

Comment: For a woman, it's more likely to be noticed if we happen to wear the same outfit twice in a row, especially by other women.  For a man, a suit is going to look samey anyway.  I'd possibly notice the same tie if it attracted my attention the first time.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Would it cause problems if I wear the same clothes for the second job interview as I did for the first one?

Not in general.

Comment: modelling agencies usually ask that people come in skinny jeans and a t-shirt when meeting scouts - models aren't expected to be fashionable themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why wearing the same clothes should cause problems.

*Dress for the job you want, not the one you have*, as the saying goes. If you're going to an interview for a managing, consulting or front-desk job, wear a clean suit and tie (for men). For a desk-job or a job in a less formal setting, wear casual professional. For a job in a startup it may be just as appropriate to wear jeans and a t-shirt.

The most important thing is to wear clean clothes, no matter how professional or casual. If you get a refusal, it's not because you wore the same clothes in several interviews, but for some other reason.